# Is it possible to turn a filter on and off conditionally in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, filter, conditional-statements, angularjs-ng-repeat

For example I have a table in which I am showing students marks of Math, Science, English and other subjects. And I  have a `checkbox` which if checked will only list the students that have  `{{student.mathMarks + student.scienceMarks > 150}}` (i.e. sum of student's math and science marks to be more than 150). And when the `checkbox` is unchecked it will again show all the students.  Is there a way I could associate a conditional filter with the given students with `ng-repeat` to achieve  this?

Following is the code relating to the case I tried explaining above:

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in students">
    <td >
        {{student.name}}
    </td>
    <td >
       {{student.mathMarks}}
    </td>
    <td >
       {{student.scienceMarks}}
    </td>
     <td >
       {{student.englishMarks}}
    </td>
</tr>

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="onlyFooStudents" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [pass a function as the expression for you filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). So in that case all you got to do is to declare a function in your scope that checks for the flag, something like:

```
$scope.yourCustomFilter = function(student) {
    // if flag is false, bring everybody. if not, bring only the ones that match.
    return $scope.onlyFooStudents || 
      student && student.mathMarks + student.scienceMarks > 150;
};
```

And in your binding you will have `ng-repeat="student in student | filter:yourCustomFilter"`.

Another way to implement it in case you're using the same filter somewhere else, is to create a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) and you can than pass in parameters, something in these lines:

```
angular.module('appFilters', []).filter('filterStudents', function() {
   function isApproved(student) {
       return student && student.mathMarks + student.scienceMarks > 150;
   }

   return function(students, showApprovedOnly) {
     // if it is to bring everybody, we just return the original array,
     // if not, we go on and filter the students in the same way.
     return !showApprovedOnly ? students : students.filter(isApproved);

     // COMPATIBLITY: please notice that Array.prototype.filter is only available IE9+.
   };
})
```

Your binding you then be `ng-repeat="student in students | studentFilter:onlyFooStudents"`. Notice that we pass in the `onlyFooStudents` as an argument to your filter, bound directly from the scope.

Comment: CaioToOn: This is simply superb. Thanks a zillion :)

Comment: This comment got me through some trouble I've been having with dynamic filters. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 3):

Create a filter that will receive an extra argument (that of the checkbox) to know when to conditionally enable/disable the filter.

```js
function FooFilter() {
  return function(data, isEnabled) {
    var result = [];
    if (angular.isArray(data) && isEnabled) {
      angular.forEach(data, function(student) {
        if (student.mathMark + student.scienceMark > 150) {
          result.push(student);
        }
      });
      return result;
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="student in students | fooFilter : filterState">
  <td>...</td>
</tr>

...
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filterState" /> Enable filter
```

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dNc2Letcs68i2uF4wQ9M?p=preview).